# testLink 1.9.20, cannot access API key

Tags: php, testlink

I'm using testLink with Robot framework for test automation.
Recently, we installed testLink on a dedicated server, retiring a testLink installation on a local VM. Data was exported from the old TL and imported with the new installation.

After the new installation, some quick checks didn't show any problems, until I tried to create a devKey (Personal API access key) for robot framework's access to the testlink db. This key is to be generated using the "My Settings" page of the application. But this page does not show anymore, a blank frame is displayed instead. A more systematic look uncovered further pages that were not shown anymore.

I have no clue why this happens and which tools to employ for further analysis.

System data:
Both installations run on virtual machines, OS is OpenSuse 15.4 in both cases. Apache is v. 2.4.51, php is V7.
Installation procedure meticiously followed the documentation (at least I think so), and gave no reasons for complaint.

What I tried since:

- tried to contact the testlink user forum, which seems to be dead since some time, as I neither could reach the forum, nor email its admin for information, as requested by the forum's error message.
- Investigated apache2 error logs.
- Compared source code of both installations, which did not yield anything interesting.
- Searched the web for "testlink", "My Settings", "bug" etc. in varying combinations.
- Followed various hints from the web, to no avail.
- Compared old and new installations, regarding installed php modules.
- Searched for hints in testLink's php source.

Apache2 log message when opening "My Settings" from the navBar with link address http: //testlink/testlink/lib/usermanagement/userInfo.php (giving a blank frame)

```
[Tue Feb 13 15:40:42.330733 2024] [php7:notice] [pid 11409] [client 192.168.2.90:60700]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function hasRight() on null in /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/lib/functions/common.php:1925

Stack trace:

#0 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/lib/functions/common.php(1643): getGrantSetWithExit()
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/lib/usermanagement/userInfo.php(22): initUserEnv()
#2 {main}
thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/lib/functions/common.php on line 1925,
referer: http://testlink/testlink/lib/general/navBar.php?tproject_id=0&tplan_id=0&updateMainPage=1
```

Apache2 log message when opening "View roles" from page "Role Management" using link http: //testlink/testlink/lib/usermanagement/rolesView.php, also resulting in a blank frame displayed.

```
[Tue Feb 13 15:43:00.856658 2024] [php7:notice] [pid 11412] [client 192.168.2.90:48402]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/gui/templates_c

/0b0c74a505ce728d1d3f154b00c8bd391ff525f0_0.file.usersAssign.tpl.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_65cb71f242f212_89907882()
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode()
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugin /smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render()
#3 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#4 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugin/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(134): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute()
#5 /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/lib/usermanagement/usersAssign.php(136): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display in /srv/www/htdocs/testlink/gui/templates_c/0b0c74a505ce728d1d3f154b00c8bd391ff525f0_0.file.usersAssign.tpl.php on line 119, referer: http://testlink/testlink/lib/usermanagement/usersView.php
```

Using "Assign Test Plan Roles" from page "Role Management" also results in a blank frame and similar log message.

I'm stuck. Because it has been working well before, what is the difference?
Could this be a problem with testLink/php/apache configuration?
Could this be related to database content in any way?
Is there anyone experiencing the similar problems?

I'd greatly appreciate any hint or any request for more elaborated description/data. The data provided is what I think could help in an analysis. But as I stated above, I have no idea what exactly happens, so please tell me what data would be more helpful.

Thanks in advance

Hynerix